# MongoDB query sort count

Tags: mongodb, bson

Hi I have 2 Game records:

**game 1** with a list of players p1(**alice**), p2(**bob**), p3(**matt**), p4(**tom**)

**game 2** with a list of players p1(**alice**), p2(**bob**), p3(**jack**), p4(**tom**)

I'd like to query my MongoDB collection games to sort the most recurrent people that appear in the same game as **BOB**. A good result in this case would be:

```
Alice: appear 2 times
Tom:  appear 2 time
Matt: appear 1 time
Jack: appear 1 time
```

In SQL I did:

```
             SELECT idplayer, COUNT(idplayer) AS countplayer 
             FROM (SELECT b.idgame, b.idplayer 
             FROM associations a, associations b 
             WHERE a.idplayer="BOB" 
             AND b.idgame=a.idgame 
             AND b.idplayer <> "BOB"
             ORDER BY b.idgame DESC LIMIT 1000) as c
             GROUP BY idplayer 
             ORDER BY countplayer DESC LIMIT 5;
```

With mongo I am trying something like:

```
gamesCollection.find("{playerid : #}","BOB").sort(//counter).limit(5)...
```

Can someone help me to fix this query for MongoDB?
Thank you

**EDIT:**

I think I am getting closer what I want, but still wrong query:

```
> db.games.aggregate("[{ $match: {playerid : 'bob'} }, {$group : { _id:null, cou
nt: { $sum: 1}} } ]")
```

please suggest a solution. thanks

**EDIT 2**

An example of a game document :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("514d9afb6e058b8a806bdbc0"), "gameid" : 1, "numofplayers" : 3,
 "playersList" : [{"playerid" : "matt" },{"playerid" : "bob"},{"playerid" : "alice"} ] }
```

Comment: Try using the aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/. There you could `$match` on the name, and `$group` on other users, `$sort`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If original document looks like:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId(...),
   players: [...]
}
```

Then you can do it using `aggregate`:

```
var playerId = 'bob';
db.records.aggregate([
  { $match: { players: playerId }},
  { $unwind: '$players' },
  { $match: { players:  { $ne: playerId } } },
  { $group: { _id: { player: '$players' }, times: { $sum : 1} } },
  { $sort: { times: -1 } }
])
```

**Upd:**

For document:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("514d9afb6e058b8a806bdbc0"), 
  "gameid" : 1, "numofplayers" : 3,
  "playersList" : [
    {"playerid" : "matt" },
    {"playerid" : "bob"},
    {"playerid" : "alice"} 
   ] 
}
```

The query is:

```
var playerId = 'bob';
db.records.aggregate([
  { $match: { 'playersList.playerid': playerId }},
  { $unwind: '$playersList' },
  { $match: { 'playersList.playerid':  { $ne: playerId } } },
  { $group: { _id: '$playersList.playerid', times: { $sum : 1} } },
  { $sort: { times: -1 } }
])
```

// I also found out that `$group` operator could be simpler

Comment: Hi, I can't work out how to replace "player" from "...{ _id: { player: '$players' }..."  with the appropriate value for my document.

A game looks like this:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("514d9afb6e058b8a806bdbc0"), "gameid" : 1, "numofplayers" : 3,
 "playersList" : [{"playerid" : "matt" },{"playerid" : "bob"},{"playerid" : "alice"} ] }

Hope you can help me. Thanks